# Django: Queries are Lazy & Creating an Instance Diff

Tags: django

I am trying to make note of the changes to a class model object to be sent to the `creator` of that class instance.

I created a utility method that diffs the two objects, however, this doesn't work since the query isn't evaluated until later:

```
goal = Goal.objects.get(pk=goal_id)
old_obj = goal

goal.description = "Some new string"
goal.save()
```

This doesn't work because when I then iterate over the model class fields, the values are the same on the old version as on the updated version.

How can I force the query to be evaluated?

There are many different kinds of objects for which this is wanted so hard coding extracting the values isn't really maintainable.

Any thoughts?

Thanks! :-)
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with queries being lazy, but a simple consequence of Python's assignment semantics. The line `old_obj = goal` does not create a copy of the `goal` object, it simply assigns `old_obj` as another name pointing to the same object. Changing the attributes of one of those object will automatically mean the other object will see the changes.

A simple way of doing this is just to ask the database for another copy:

```
goal = Goal.objects.get(pk=goal_id)
old_obj = Goal.objects.get(pk=goal_id)
```

Now they will be two separate objects, even though they point to the same database row, and changes to one won't affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use `list()` on a `QuerySet` to force it to evaluate](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: Thank you Daniel. However, I use .get() and do not actually get a queryset returned but rather the class instance. I updated the title of my post since that was confusing.